# Electric Shock from concrete pad

Tags: electrical

MY band recently played a gig at a friend's farm. We set up on a concrete pad behind his barn. I received my first shock when I set my arm on the top of my guitar amplifier. It was a hot sunny day and my arm was a little sweaty. Shock was minor. I then touched one of my effects pedals with my hand to adjust settings while holding my guitar with my other hand and received a very severe shock that literally knocked me off my feet. Our bass player's amplifier (next to me) completely fried as did a replacement amp. Our other guitar player who set up on other side of stage had no issues even though he was using same cord/circuit. We changed power cords, used different circuits, etc. The only thing that finally solved the problem was by plugging our gear into the extension chords on the ***other side of the pad***. In other words, the issue was somehow related to the place on the pad where we were setup. Have you ever heard of such a thing? In 30 years playing, none of us had ever come across anything like this. We are all pretty good at tracking down electrical issues. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: were the other cords plugged into different or same outlets? are there any DIY parts on the bad cords? sounds to me like the bad cords and/or the outlets they used are mis-wired. maybe the outlet has a hot neutral and the cord has transposed neutral and ground.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like the barn did not have proper [equipotential bonding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_bonding), which lead to a voltage potential between different areas of the barn.

Your cord was plugged in where ground was 0 volts, and your equipment was set up where ground was a different 0 volts. Because of the lack of equipotential bonding, there's an electrical potential difference between the two grounds.